# Create list of unique values from XML child node values using Python 3.x

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I am trying to create a unique list of GRADE values (in the example below, the resulting set would be: GR12, GR10, GR9, GR11):

```
<School>
<SchoolNumber>123456</SchoolNumber>
<Students>
    <Student>
        <ID>1</ID><Grade>GR12</Grade><Name>A. Green</Name>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <ID>2</ID><Grade>GR9</Grade><Name>B. Green</Name>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <ID>1</ID><Grade>GR12</Grade><Name>A. Blue</Name>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <ID>2</ID><Grade>GR9</Grade><Name>B. Blue</Name>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <ID>3</ID><Grade>GR11</Grade><Name>C. Blue</Name>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <ID>1</ID><Grade>GR9</Grade><Name>A. Redd</Name>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <ID>2</ID><Grade>GR9</Grade><Name>B. Redd</Name>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <ID>3</ID><Grade>GR10</Grade><Name>C. Redd</Name>
    </Student>
</Students>
```

I used the XML ElementTree to generate a list of all GRADE values, and then attempted to create unique list using a set() as follows:

```
grades = root.findall('.//{http://anysite.com}Grade')
unique_grades = list(set(grades))
```

however, the unique_grades[] list contains the same number of elements as the grades[] list.  I've been reading through the https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html
documentation (I'm totally new to Python and learning as I go) but I can't figure this out.  Any suggestions/help would be very much appreciated.  Regards, Dave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're supposed to call `set` using element's inner-texts not the elements itself. The former will do string comparisons, while the latter will compare `Element` objects *by reference*, which won't change the number of elements in the output since the input is already a set of distinct objects :

```
grades = root.findall('.//{http://anysite.com}Grade')
unique_grades = list(set(g.text for g in grades))
```

Comment: Hi har07.  Thank you for your time and explaining how that works (much appreciated). Dave.